# Combining boolean evaluation with indexing change without list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, boolean-logic

I'm working on a problem that involves subdividing edges that are stored as indices in three index arrays because the project requires knowing information at the previous node, current node, and next node.

For example, a set of 3 edges is being subdivided at each edge to produce a set of 6 edges.

The edge information is initially input as two index matrices, with the following geometric information.

```
Global information matrix (key to index)
<Key>   <Global Location>
"1"            0
"0"            1
"3"            2
"2"            3
```

The corresponding coordinate information in a numpy matrix is:

```
 <Coordinates>
 [[3.0, 0.0, 3.0]
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  [10.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  [7.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

The directional connectivity (pt0, pt1) is stored as index matrices,

```
pt0_index = [1 0 3 0]
pt1_index = [0 1 2 3]
pt2_index = [3 0 0 2]
```

My first question is if there is a way to store a "Null" value in the pt0 index and pt2 index for keys "0" and "3" respectively. I've been getting around any problems with the boundary condition nodes via logical arrays, as follows:

```
start_pts = [False True False False]
end_pts   = [False False True False]
```

My next question concerns being able to isolate the edge indices that need to change during the subdivision. I've been accomplishing this via several for loops, but I think there must be a better way. For the purposes of this example, all 3 edges will be subdivided, so new points will be added to the global information matrix, which is now:

```
Global information matrix (key to index)
<Key>   <Global Location>
"1"            0
"0"            1
"3"            2
"2"            3
"4"            4
"5"            5
"6"            6

 <Coordinates>
 [[3.0, 0.0, 3.0]
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  [10.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  [7.0, 0.0, 3.0]
  [1.5, 0.0, 1.5]
  [8.5, 0.0, 1.5]
  [5.0, 0.0, 3.0]]
```

Based on these insertions, the index arrays for pt0, pt1, and pt2 should now be as follows:

```
pt0 = [4 0 5 6 1 3 0]
pt1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
pt2 = [6 4 0 5 0 2 3]
```

*Remember that the duplicate "0" indices are due to start and end nodes

I have a function that returns the edge indices as tuples for the new points.

i.e.

```
new_edges = set([(1, 0), (3, 2), (0, 3)})
```

I am editing the index matrices through a series of for loops as follows (example given for the start edges):

```
ind_change = []
for pt,_ in new edges:
    all_pts = where(pt0_index == pt)[0][:].tolist()
    for sub_pt in all_pts:
        if start_pts[sub_pt] == False:
            ind_change.append(sub_pt)
```

Basically I want the index locations that are in the start point for new edges (0, 2, 3) without the start point index

Is there a way to combine the boolean evaluation with the index search?

Comment: I don't understand the first 2 sentences. Is this a graph theoretical problem?

Comment: YOu don't need the `[:].tolist()` part. It can iterate on the `where(...)[0]` array.

Comment: @Elmex80s, I am working with a network data structure where nodes are connected by directional edges. The calculations I am doing at each node only require knowledge of the previous node location, the current node location, and the next node location in space.

Comment: I think you give us way _too_ much information. The first question can be asked on its own. The first question is numpy related isn't it?

Comment: @Elmex80s, agreed. I'm rephrasing this as 2 questions. Thanks for the feedback!